# Cyclical inheritance between classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, methods

I want to group the actions that a player can do in a class called "Action".
These actions consist of updating the player's bank account balance when he buy or sell something. This implies being able to call the "get_account" method of the "Player" class from the "Action" class. To do this, I add the notion of heritability between these 2 classes by writing
`class Action (Player):`

Here is my full code

```
from typing import Any


class BankAccount:
    name: str
    balance: float

    def __init__(self, name: str, balance: float) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance


class Player(Action):
    name: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.account_bank = None

    def set_account(self, name, balance) -> None:
        self.account_bank = BankAccount(name, balance)

    def get_account(self) -> BankAccount:
        return self.account

    def action(self, choice, price):
        if choice == 1:
            self.buy_something(price)
        if choice == 2:
            self.sell_something(price)
        else:
            pass


class Action(Player):
    def buy_something(self, price):
        self.get_account().balance -= price

    def sell_something(self, price):
        self.get_account().balance += price


kwargs = {'name': 'jason'}
jason = Player(**kwargs)  # Create player 'jason'
jason.set_account('my_account', 100)  # Adds Jason an account with $ 100

jason.action(1, 20)  # buy something for 20 dollars
jason.action(2, 15)  # sell something for 15 dollars
```

My problem is that I also need to be able to call the methods of the "Action" class from the "Player" class. Indeed, the "Player" class has an "action" method which allows you to make a choice among the methods grouped in the "Action" class. (I really need to be able to group a player's list of actions into a dedicated class)

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need `Action` to inherit from anything. Just remove the inheritance (`class Action:`) and move it above `class Player`.

Comment: Can you provide some more background why you need such a setup? With such a close coupling, why are ``Action`` and ``Player`` even two separate classes? Why is ``Action`` a concrete class and not just and abstract or mixin class?

Comment: @quamrana, If I remove the inheritance from the "Action" class, how can I call the from it the "get_account()" method of the 'Player' class ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I don't understand the concept of "abstract or mixin class".
To try to explain the context of my problem ... I want to develop a Reinforcement Learning model to make an agent (a Player) evolve in his environment. At each step the agent must take an action. For the sake of clarity, I wanted to group the actions that it can take so that they don't get mixed up with the unrelated set_account () or get_account () methods.

Comment: @David: I don't understand. What happened when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @quamrana, I get the following error : "Unresolved attribute reference 'get_account' for class 'Action'  from my IDE (Pycharm)

```
class Action:

    def buy_something(self, price):
        self.get_account().balance -= price

    def sell_something(self, price):
        self.get_account().balance += price
```

Comment: Abstract and mixin classes are classes which cannot be instantiated. They only serves as pieces to complete other classes via inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how the context or reinforcement learning requires this kind of setup. In specific, why is the concept of getting/setting an account entirely separate from the concept of using that account (to buy/sell)? It seems like ``Action`` should own ``account_bank`` or be entirely removed.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your comments and suggestions, I think I was not clear enough in my explanations. I will try to rephrase my request in a new question

Answer (score 0):

I also think that you have a typo. The `get_account()` method should be this:

```
    def get_account(self):
        return self.account_bank
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29152189)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: There is a possibility the OP is confused and doesn't realise that this is the root cause.